# Как решить задачу поиска?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть 150 гигов данных о разных компаниях. Нужно придумать как быстро получать из них нужную запись. Например у компании name = 'ооо "рога и копыта"'. Пользователь вводит рога и ему сразу ответ. Как у google в выпадающем меню. Какую базу данных использовать лучше и как организовать в ней данные?

Comment: Apache lucene, через механизм suggester-ов.

Comment: любую БД поддерживающую "полнотекстовый поиск" (в гугле искать по этому термину)

Comment: Сколько всего организаций в 150гиг?

Comment: Все Российские + часть Европейских и Американских за 20 лет. То есть есть те которых уже нет.

Comment: А сейчас эти 150гиг в каком формате?

Comment: В формате json.

Comment: Можете выдать хотя бы один образец организации из этого Json'a для экспериментов?

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять Cassandra из DSE (DataStacks Enterprise), [который интегрируется с SOLR](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-enterprise-cassandra-with-solr-integration-details).

Пример вставки данных:

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_category JSON '{
  "category" : "GC", 
  "points" : 780, 
  "id" : "829aa84a-4bba-411f-a4fb-38167a987cda",
  "lastname" : "SUTHERLAND" }';
```

При помощи [`CREATE SEARCH INDEX`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateSearchIndex.html) создается полнотекстовый индекс для поиска по SOLR:

Потом можно искать вот так:

```
select * from keyspace.table_name
where solr_query='{fq:"common_col":"filter_values" q:"col_name":"values"}'
```